# Using subdomains with heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .htaccess, heroku, dns

Very tedious issue, I have a model in my application which has a subdomain field, this is then used as a constraint in the routing so that I can access the show page of this model through its subdomain. It works perfectly locally, yet, when I push to heroku the app doesn't work, at all.

Using cloudflare for DNS:

```
CNAME - mydomain.com - alias of myapp.herokuapp.com
CNAME - www - alias of myapp.herokuapp.com
```

Heroku custom domains:

```
mydomain.com
www.mydomain.com
myapp.herokuapp.com
```

Any idea as to why this set up isn't working properly? I used the railscast revised tutorial on subdomain implementation if that helps. Any feedback would be a dream.

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup a wildcard DNS entry pointing to your Heroku application

`CNAME - *.mydomain.com - alias of myapp.herokuapp.com`

and add `*.mydomain.com` as a custom domain in Heroku.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168826-Does-CloudFlare-support-wildcard-DNS-entries-